# A different instance loading and persistent preference behaviour of Xamarin.Forms application in Debug/Release

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I have a simple MVVM Xamarin.Forms application which serves as a client for push notifications. The notifications are send from my backend via Firebase. The application has Android version only. Recently, I've updated my application to store the notification payloads as a persistent setting via `Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences`. I have binding between a label text and a property in a view-model. The property handling storing/retrieving operations.

My problem is related to application loading. In debug, when I click on a received push notification, I jump into the application where I can see the notification text with a timestamp like I want. When I kill the application/received another notification, I see them when I load the application one way or another.

In release, when I click on a received push notification, I jump into the application where **I can't see** the notification text. The label text is blank which is the default state. I can see the notification text if I load the application via launcher or if I switch to the application via task manager. The kill of the application resets the stored notifications.

**My question is why there is a different behaviour between debug/release and have the same behaviour in both modes**. I think that it is related to how Android application threats instances.

### Notes

The source code is mostly a default Xamarin.Forms template from Visual Studio with the latest versions of NuGet packages.

The delivery of push notifications is fine in both modes, the difference is how application loads `App` or `MainPage` class when I click on a delivered notification itself.

Comment: From your description, you means that firebase notification can not receive when you application is in release model, but it has no problem in debug mode?

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT Please, see updates notes in my description.

Comment: firebase notification send by service implements an OnTokenRefresh method that is invoked when the registration token is initially created or changed, you can add breakpoint at OnTokenRefresh method to see if there is difference for debug and release.